# Is it possible to change Angular scope in jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Thats my code:

```
.directive('Search', function($templateRequest, $compile) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, $scope){
                $templateRequest('/js/angularjs/search.html').then(function(html){
                    var template = angular.element(html);
                    element.append(template);
                    $compile(template)(scope);
                    $('#multipleSelect').multipleSelect({
                        test: console.log($scope),
                        onClick: function(view, scope) {
                            //view.checked ? scope.searchByTitle.multi.push(view.value) : scope.searchByTitle.multi.remove(view.value);
                            console.log('scope:');
                            console.log($scope);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

I am using this plugin:
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

I wanna achieve that after I change one of multiple select value, I wanna push sth into AngularJS scope as well (bascially use onClick event). But scope is not accessible inside jQuery function...

If you have any workaround idea about this, I'd like to hear that as well :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onClick: function(view, scope) {
    var scope = angular.element($("#multipleSelect")).scope();
    view.checked ? scope.searchByTitle.multi.push(view.value) : scope.searchByTitle.multi.remove(view.value);
}
```

Thats my solution I managed to find. It works :)